# WFFM - Sitecore : linking dropdown to user profile

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore 8 Update 2 and the WFFM module.
I created a register page using WFFM and everything works fine except for the values in the dropdown lists ( zipcode, city, gender, ... )

I linked all the form fields to the profile fields but these values never get filled in. I tried linking the form dropdown to a dropdown field on the profile, to a simple text field on the profile, but it never fills in any value.

Does anyone know why this is and what i can do to link these fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in WFFM. To fix it, add the code below to your solution then go to the item `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/List Types/Drop List` and set the field `MVC Type` to `{your namespace}.DropListField,[your dll name}`

```
namespace {your namespace}
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Controls.Data;

/// <summary>
/// The drop list field.
/// </summary>
public class DropListField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.DropListField
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="DropListField"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">
    /// The item.
    /// </param>
    public DropListField(Item item)
        : base(item)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The get result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="ControlResult"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override ControlResult GetResult()
    {
        var value = this.Value as List<string>;
        var selectListItem = this.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == value.First());
        var str = selectListItem != null ? selectListItem.Text : string.Empty;
        return new ControlResult(this.ID.ToString(), this.Title, selectListItem != null ? selectListItem.Value : string.Empty, str);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This helps, but the text-value is being stored instead of the value-value.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be this bug:

http://www.cmsbestpractices.com/bug-sitecore-8-with-web-forms-for-marketers-drop-list-entries-not-being-properly-recorded-in-xdb/

Use Robomongo to  check if the values are being stored properly in MongoDB.

Comment: i tried this, didn't help.
Edit: where would these values be stored in MongoDB ?